# How to continue the execution of python script as a different user

Tags: python

I want to execute a python script which executes the following command in order:

```
sudo su - postgres         #change user to postgres
psql                       #enter the psql command promt from 
create user user_name with password 'mypassword';             #
create database voylla_development with encoding = 'utf8';    #all the 3 commands are to be executed in psql command prompt
grant all on database voylla_development to user_name;        #
exit           #psql prompt
exit           #postgres user
cat <backup_file_name> | zcat - | PGPASSWORD=mypassword psql -d voylla_development -h localhost -p 5432 -U user_name
```

I tried using subprocess and os.system():

```
cmd='sudo -u postgres psql'
args = shlex.split(cmd)
p=subprocess.Popen(args)
p.wait()

cmd1='psql'
args1 = shlex.split(cmd1)
p=subprocess.Popen(args1)
p.wait()

##and so on for each command
```

But the script stops after I login as postgres user. How can I continue the script after user change?
Thanks

**EDIT:** using psycopg2 helped the cause

Comment: `Popen()` instances are separate processes; you are not retaining the shell.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : how can I do that(retain shell)? Is it possible using subprocess or should I look for something else?

Comment: Why not run your Python script as root instead? `sudo yourscript.py`.

Comment: didn't help...same thing again

Comment: That was a separate question; the same remark, the session with `psql` doesn't carry over to a new command. A second `Popen()` instance runs a new program, it does not send commands to the old one. Use `pexpect` or write directly to the `stdin` of the first `Popen()` process.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `Popen()` object, you start a *new* program. You are not communicating with an open `psql` shell.

You either have to drive `psql` directly by setting `stdin` to `subprocess.PIPE`, or, much easier, use [`pexpect`](http://www.noah.org/wiki/pexpect) to drive the `psql` shell:

```
import pexpect

psql = pexpect.spawn('psql')
psql.expect('=>')  # wait for the prompt
psql.send('create user user_name with password 'mypassword';')
# etc.
```